# how to display auto-increment id values for every registration in a webpage?

Tags: html, mysqli, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I created the database in phpmyadmin using mysqli in wampserver.I need to display auto-increment value for every registration in a webpage.How to get that value?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a PHP script to access your database?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the auto incremented values when creating a table. 
Set your table structure Primary ID to auto increment.

Please see the image below

[Auto Incremented table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOep7.png)

Comment: thank for your reply..i was created that auto-increment value..i need to know how to display that auto-increment value in html-webpage ..ie the field in html automatically increased for every login or registration.can i display that auto-increment value to particular fields in webpage.

Comment: and in every login you must define a column which will check status if it is '1' then it online, if 2 it is offline. then count all of status which is 1 then it would increment the value. It would be proper to count end not perform incremental value. if you want to count times logged create a marker then get that value and increment it everytime the user login.